# Let $Y$ be a closed subspace of a real normed space $X$ and $x \in X \setminus Y$. Show that $d(x,Y) > 0$

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Let $Y$ be a closed subspace of a real normed space $X$ and $x \in X \setminus Y$. Show that $d(x,Y) > 0$.

I'm not sure, but isn't this trivial? Since $x \notin Y$ but $x \in X$ and $Y$ a closed subspace of $X$ we have that $d(x,Y) > 0$.

$d(x,Y) = 0 \iff \exists y \in Y : x = y$ but this is not possible since $x \notin Y$ but $y \in Y$.

Is that correct?

**Answer (with the help of Mark and Sourav Gosh):**

This not as trivial as thought in the first place (but still easy to show). Note that $d(x,Y) = \inf \{d(x,y) : y \in Y\}$ could be $0$ without $x \in Y$. I think one can imagine that if we pick a point $y_1 \in Y$ there is always a point $y_2 \in Y$ closer to $x \in X \setminus Y$. Therefore, $d(x,Y) = 0$ but still $x \notin Y$.

Let's assume that $d(x,Y) = \inf \{d(x,y) : y \in Y\} = 0$

We can construct a sequence $(y_n)_n$ such that $d(x,y_n) \to 0$ i.e. $y_n \to x$. Therefore, $x \in \bar{Y}$.

So, we've shown that $d(x,Y) = \inf \{d(x,y) : y \in Y\} = 0 \implies x \in \bar{Y}$. Therefore if $x \notin  \bar{Y}$, we have that $d(x,Y) > 0$.

Comment: The distance is defined as $d(x,Y)=\inf\{d(x,y): y\in Y\}$. This number can be $0$ even if $x$ doesn't belong to $Y$. In order to solve the problem you need to use the fact that $Y$ is closed.

Comment: Prove : $\begin{align}d(x, Y)&=\inf\{d(x, y) :y\in Y\}\\&=0 \\&\implies x\in \overline{Y}\end{align}$

Comment: Could the following be an idea: Suppose $d(x,Y) = 0$ i.e. $\inf \{d(x,y): y \in Y\} = 0$. Then I can construct a sequence $(y_n)_n \in Y$ such that $d(x,y_n) \to 0$ i.e. $y_n \to x$. Therefore, $x \in \bar{Y}$?

Comment: Yes, that's how you prove it.

Comment: Thanks! I do see - intuitively - that such a sequence must exist. Is there, however, a formal argumentation here?

Comment: @R.S. Of course. Since the infimum is $0$, for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$ there must be some $y_n\in Y$ such that $d(x,y_n)<\frac{1}{n}$. This way you get a sequence.